# Inserir tela de boas vindas no projeto

Tags: c#

Como eu faço para inserir uma tela de boas vindas com um botão para continuar e abrir o sistema?

no form incial está assim:

```
namespace App_Herois_da_Fe
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Conexao.CriarBancoSQLite();
        Conexao.CriarTabelaSQLite();
    }
```

o nome do form da tela de boas vindas é: frmBoasVindas.cs

Comment: mas qual a sua dúvida? você já tem o form (frmBoasVindas), o que não está funcionando? já deu uma pesquisada em *Splash Screen*?

Comment: @RicardoPontual é que eu não domino a linguagem de programação, eu sou estudante que está tentando adquirir experiencia na linguagem ao qual tem que dividir a busca do conhecimento com o Java ao qual a faculdade exige, eu vejo alguns tutoriais e pra mim não faz muito sentido por ser abrangente, e assim me enrola. o splash tem o temporizador e com isso envolvem mais elementos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um Form e chamálo pelo método Show que irá carregar o form e continuar o processamento após o mesmo ser aberto, e dentro do form de boas vindas implementa a regra que deseja para fechar o mesmo.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Conexao.CriarBancoSQLite();
    Conexao.CriarTabelaSQLite();
    frmBoasVindas oForm = new frmBoasVindas();
    oForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou.